Thermostat is not discovered by Alexa App when adding RangeController Interface
I got a alexa skill developed by me. When I try to log in in the skill after adding the RangeController interface my devices aren't showing up, everything worked fine previous to the addition of the new interface. I got the JSON of the Discovery returned with the list of devices but the Alexa app isn't able to recognize them.
The Discovery response when the devices doesn't show up in the app:
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "name": "Discover.Response",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "messageId": "3f178189-ac15-41a5-af4d-6d0da551491b"
        },
        "payload": {
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "endpointId": "17202003@1d417d4b092a922a95761ed5909d2b65d866a3e4",
                    "manufacturerName": "Mnix",
                    "friendlyName": "Faucet - 17202003",
                    "description": "17202003",
                    "displayCategories": [
                        "OTHER"
                    ],
                    "cookie": {},
                    "capabilities": [
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa",
                            "version": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "powerState"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": false,
                                "retrievable": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.ThermostatController",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "targetSetpoint"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "proactivelyReported": false,
                                "retrievable": false
                            },
                            "configuration": {
                                "lockoutTemperature": {
                                    "heating": {
                                        "maximum": {
                                            "value": 61,
                                            "scale": "CELSIUS"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "interface": "Alexa.RangeController",
                            "instance": "Faucet.Temperature",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [{
                                    "name": "rangeValue"
                                }],
                                "proactivelyReported": false,
                                "retrievable": false,
                                "nonControllable": false
                            },
                            "configuration": {
                                "supportedRange": {
                                    "minimumValue": 1,
                                    "maximumValue": 61,
                                    "precision": 1
                                },
                                "presets": [
                                    {
                                        "rangeValue": 1,
                                        "presetResources": {
                                            "friendlyNames": [{
                                                    "@type": "asset",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "assetId": "Alexa.Value.Low"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "@type": "text",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "text": "Baja",
                                                        "locale": "es-ES"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "rangeValue": 30,
                                        "presetResources": {
                                            "friendlyNames": [{
                                                    "@type": "asset",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "assetId": "Alexa.Value.Medium"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "@type": "text",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "text": "Media",
                                                        "locale": "es-ES"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "rangeValue": 61,
                                        "presetResources": {
                                            "friendlyNames": [{
                                                    "@type": "asset",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "assetId": "Alexa.Value.Maximum"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "@type": "asset",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "assetId": "Alexa.Value.High"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "@type": "text",
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "text": "Alta",
                                                        "locale": "es-ES"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I've tried using the RangeController as a substitute as mentioned in the next blog post, but no luck.
https://community.openhab.org/t/alexa-thermostat-will-not-allow-setpoint-greater-than-99-f/124965/5
